# Formatting the months and dates in a subplot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, time-series, datetime-format

I am trying to create a time series of the sea surface temperature data over the whole year for six consecutive years and plot them using the subplots. I want to mark the x-ticks as the months. I tried using the `matplotlib.dates` option. However the years doesn't change on the subsequent subplots.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import set_epoch

arrays14 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2014.ascii')] #loading the data
arrays15 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2015.ascii')]
arrays16 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2016.ascii')]
arrays17 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2017.ascii')]
arrays18 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2018.ascii')]
arrays19 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2019.ascii')]

arrays14 = np.delete(arrays14,[0,1,2,3,4],0) #deleting the headers
arrays15 = np.delete(arrays15,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays16 = np.delete(arrays16,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays17 = np.delete(arrays17,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays18 = np.delete(arrays18,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays19 = np.delete(arrays19,[0,1,2,3,4,215,216,217],0)
sst14 = []
for i in arrays14:
    d1 = i[0]
    d2 = i[2]
    sst1 = i[2]
    sst14.append(sst1)
    datetime1.append(d1)
    datetime2.append(d2)
sst14 = np.array(sst14,dtype = np.float64)
sst_14_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst14,-9.99) #masking the fillvalues

sst15 = []
for i in arrays15:
    sst2 = i[2]
    sst15.append(sst2)
sst15 = np.array(sst15,dtype = np.float64)
sst_15_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst15,-9.99)

sst16 = []
for i in arrays16:
    sst3 = i[2]
    sst16.append(sst3)
sst16 = np.array(sst16,dtype = np.float64)
sst_16_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst16,-9.99)

sst17 = []
for i in arrays17:
    sst4 = i[2]
    sst17.append(sst4)
sst17 = np.array(sst17,dtype = np.float64)
sst_17_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst17,-9.99)

sst18 = []
for i in arrays18:
    sst5 = i[2]
    sst18.append(sst5)

sst18 = np.array(sst18,dtype = np.float64)
sst_18_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst18,-9.99)
np.shape(sst18)
sst19 = []
for i in arrays19:
    sst6 = i[2]
    sst19.append(sst6)
sst19 = np.array(sst19,dtype = np.float64)
sst19_u = np.zeros(len(sst14), dtype = np.float64)
sst19_fill = np.full([118],-9.99,dtype=np.float64)

sst19_u[0:211] = sst19[0:211]
sst19_u[211:329] = sst19_fill
sst19_u[329:365] = sst19[211:247]

sst_19_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst19_u,-9.99)

##########Plotting
new_epoch = '2016-01-01T00:00:00'
mdates.set_epoch(new_epoch)
fig, axs=plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12, 8),constrained_layout=True)
axs = axs.ravel()
axs[0].plot(sst_14_m)
axs[1].plot(sst_15_m)
axs[2].plot(sst_16_m)
axs[3].plot(sst_17_m)
axs[4].plot(sst_18_m)
axs[5].plot(sst_19_m)
for i in range(6):
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    axs[i].xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(axs[i].xaxis.get_major_locator()))
    #axs[i].grid(True)
    axs[i].set_ylim(bottom=25, top=32)
    
    axs[i].set_ylabel('SST')
plt.show()
```

I got an output like the following:
[image]

I would like to change the xlabels as 2016,2017,2018,2019 etc.

The data can be found in the folder - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bETa7PjWKIUNS13xg3RgIMa5L7bpYn5W?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you confirm if you want the data from 2016-2019ish in a single subplot with x-ticks for months?

Comment: @medium-dimensional yes, just like as shown in the figure. Six subplots for the years 2014-2019 with x-ticks for the months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love NumPy as much as the next person but this is a good use case for [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/). Pandas has the advantage of being able to label rows with more meaningful things than just positional index. For example, you can use dates. This is very convenient.

First, load your data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

dfs = []
for fname in glob.glob('./sst15n90e_dy_*.ascii'):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname, skiprows=4, delimiter='\s+')
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Now do `df.head()` and you'll see this:

[image: Initial data load]

Let's convert that date to a 'datetime' object, and use it as the index instead of the default row numbers. We'll also deal with those `-9.99` values.

```py
import numpy as np

df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YYYYMMDD'], format='%Y%m%d')
df = df.set_index('ds')
df = df.sort_index()
df.loc[df['SST'] == -9.99, 'SST'] = np.nan
```

Now you have a dataset you can do all sorts of magic with, like `df.resample('Y')['SST'].sum()` shows you the annual sum of `SST`.

Anyway, now we can make plots in various ways. You can plot DataFrames directly, eg check out `df.groupby(df.index.year)['SST'].plot()`. Or you can use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) (check out the gallery!), which understands DataFrames. Or you can construct a plot  with `matplotlib` in the usual way. For instance:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter


fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8), sharey=True)

for ax, (year, group) in zip(axs.flat, df.groupby(df.index.year)):
    ax.plot(group['SST'])
    ax.set_title(year)
    ax.grid(c='k', alpha=0.15)
    date_form = DateFormatter("%b")
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
plt.tight_layout()
```

This is close to what you wanted, but with a more useful data structure and quite a bit less code:

[image: The resulting plot]

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications and got the results as desired:

```
from pickletools import float8
import os
import numpy as np
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import set_epoch
from datetime import datetime
# for files in os.listdir('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily'):
#      path = (files)
#      print(path)
#      arrays = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open(files)]

arrays14 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2014.ascii')] #loading the data
arrays15 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2015.ascii')]
arrays16 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2016.ascii')]
arrays17 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2017.ascii')]
arrays18 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2018.ascii')]
arrays08 = [np.asarray(list(map(str, line.split()))) for line in open('/home/swadhin/project/sst/daily/sst15n90e_dy_2008.ascii')]

arrays14 = np.delete(arrays14,[0,1,2,3,4],0) #deleting the headers
arrays15 = np.delete(arrays15,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays16 = np.delete(arrays16,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays17 = np.delete(arrays17,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays18 = np.delete(arrays18,[0,1,2,3,4],0)
arrays08 = np.delete(arrays08,[0,1,2,3,4,215,216,217],0)
sst14 = []
datetime1 = []   #year, month,date
#datetime2 = []   #hour,min,second
for i in arrays14:
    d1 = i[0]
    #d2 = i[2]
    sst1 = i[2]
    sst14.append(sst1)
    datetime1.append(d1)
    #datetime2.append(d2)
#reading the data
# datetime1 = np.array(datetime1,dtype = np.float64)
# datetime2 = np.array(datetime2,dtype = np.float64)
sst14 = np.array(sst14,dtype = np.float64)
sst_14_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst14,-9.99) #masking the fillvalues

sst15 = []
datetime2 = [] 
for i in arrays15:
    d2 = i[0]
    sst2 = i[2]
    sst15.append(sst2)
    datetime2.append(d2)
sst15 = np.array(sst15,dtype = np.float64)
sst_15_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst15,-9.99)

sst16 = []
datetime3 = [] 
for i in arrays16:
    d3 = i[0]
    sst3 = i[2]
    sst16.append(sst3)
    datetime3.append(d3)
sst16 = np.array(sst16,dtype = np.float64)
sst_16_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst16,-9.99)

sst17 = []
datetime4 = [] 
for i in arrays17:
    d4 = i[0]
    sst4 = i[2]
    sst17.append(sst4)
    datetime4.append(d4)
sst17 = np.array(sst17,dtype = np.float64)
sst_17_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst17,-9.99)

sst18 = []
datetime5 = [] 
for i in arrays18:
    d5 = i[0]
    sst5 = i[2]
    sst18.append(sst5)
    datetime5.append(d5)
sst18 = np.array(sst18,dtype = np.float64)
sst_18_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst18,-9.99)

sst08 = []
datetime6 = [] 
for i in arrays08:
    d6 = i[0]
    sst6 = i[2]
    sst08.append(sst6)
    datetime6.append(d6)
sst08 = np.array(sst08,dtype = np.float64)
# sst08_u = np.zeros(len(sst14), dtype = np.float64)
# sst08_fill = np.full([118],-9.99,dtype=np.float64)
# sst08_u[0:211] = sst08[0:211]
# sst08_u[211:329] = sst08_fill
# sst08_u[329:365] = sst08[211:247]
sst_08_m = np.ma.masked_equal(sst08,-9.99)

dt = np.asarray([datetime1,datetime2,datetime3,datetime4,datetime5,datetime6])

dt_m = []
for i in dt:
    dt_m1= []
    for j in i:
        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(j,'%Y%m%d')
        dt_m1.append(datetime_object)
    dt_m.append(dt_m1)

##########Plotting
# new_epoch = '2016-01-01T00:00:00'
# mdates.set_epoch(new_epoch)
fig, axs=plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12, 8),constrained_layout=True)
axs = axs.ravel()
axs[0].plot_date(dt_m[5],sst_08_m,'-')
axs[1].plot_date(dt_m[0],sst_14_m,'-')
axs[2].plot_date(dt_m[1],sst_15_m,'-')
axs[3].plot_date(dt_m[2],sst_16_m,'-')
axs[4].plot_date(dt_m[3],sst_17_m,'-')
axs[5].plot_date(dt_m[4],sst_18_m,'-')
for i in range(6):
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    axs[i].xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    axs[i].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(axs[i].xaxis.get_major_locator()))
    axs[i].grid(True)
    axs[i].set_ylim(bottom=25, top=32)
    axs[i].set_ylabel('SST')


plt.show()
```

And it solved the issue.
[image]